# D'où viens-tu ? or Tu viens d'où ?

Tags: grammaire

In my online course it says that asking where do you come from is like “D’où viens-tu ?” but I've watched a french beginner video and in the video it says “Tu viens d'où ?” for the question. I am guessing that it is only a matter of formality but I'm not sure if there is a rule or anything.

The video with the timestamp:
https://youtu.be/V0mOUg3zK_A

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're correct that it essentially comes down to a choice. You can read more, e.g., [here](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/how-to-ask-a-question-in-french).